# Flash events on mouse over

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there any way to find out what methods get called when moving the mouse over an object in a Flash project?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to get a list of all the listeners registered to an object's ROLL_OVER and MOUSE_OVER events?

Comment: @shanethehat, basically. When I move the mouse over an object, methods are getting called. I want to see, when they are called, what the methods are.

Comment: @The_asMan, Flash Builder 4.5.

Comment: Do you already have a reference to the specific object that is being moused over, or do you need to find that as well?

Comment: U should get methods or listners or both?

Comment: Do you need the method body or simply the method signature ?

Comment: @George Profenza, just the method name would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far @rvmook's partial solution is the closest from my point of view. It would help if you use DisplayObjectContainer's [getObjectsUnderPoint()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint%28%29) method to get a list of display objects you roll over, then loop through them and check which one has rollover/mouseover event handlers, then continue drilling down.

So one short solution would be:

1. Load the swf you want to find out the name of that rollover/mouseover handler.*
2. Add a rollover handler(with bubbles set to true)
3. In the rollover handler loop through the objects under the mouse that have rollover/mouseover handlers and get their details.

**Note!**  *getObjectsUnderPoint()* works if the loading swf has permissions from the domain hosting the loaded swf. One way to find [areInaccessibleObjectsUnderPoint()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#areInaccessibleObjectsUnderPoint%28%29) method. If you own the loaded swf there shouldn't be any problems. Otherwise you either need a crossdomain.xml on the domain hosting the loaded swf granting the loader swf's domain access (and the loader swf should pass `new LoaderContext(true)` as the second parameter for load() method of the Loader intance) or use a server side script in the language of your choice to proxy/copy over the loaded swf first.

Here's a basic example of what I mean:

```
package{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.sampler.getMemberNames;

    public class BasicInfoTest extends Sprite{

        private var cursor:Point = new Point();

        public function BasicInfoTest(){
            init();
        }
        private function init():void{
            var loader:Loader = addChild(new Loader) as Loader;
            loader.load(new URLRequest('B.swf'));
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,onOver);
        }
        private function onOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
            cursor.x = mouseX;cursor.y = mouseY;
            var obj:Array = getObjectsUnderPoint(cursor);
            var numObj:int = obj.length; 
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < numObj ; i++){//look for objects under cursor that have rollover/mouseover event handlers
                if(obj[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER) || obj[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)){
                    var members:Object = getMemberNames(obj[i]);//use @rvmook's method to get listeners
                    for each (var name:QName in members){
                        if (name.localName == "listeners"){
                            for (var j : int = 0; j < obj[i][name].length; j++){
                                var func:Function = obj[i][name][j];
                                try{
                                    func.call();
                                }catch(error:Error){
                                    trace('Methods called on mouse over:',error.message.split('on ')[1].split('.')[0]);//parse error message, you might need to adapt this
                                    trace('StackTrace',error.getStackTrace()); 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should do if you only need to find out the name of the method.
If you need further information, you could access the loaded swf's bytearray and parse the actionscript bytecode to get information. I must admit binary and assembly are a bit out of my reach, but luckily there some great libraries out there to decompile swf files at runtime in as3. [AS3SWF](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki) is a brilliant one, but does not deal much with actionscript tags, while [as3commons](http://as3commons.org) is a great collection of libraries the specialize on the code aspect.

Here is an adaptation of the previous example that uses the as3-commons libraries([bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/index.html),[lang](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/index.html),[logging](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-logging/index.html) and [reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/index.html)) to display the method signature and body(as AVM2 instructions):

```
package{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.sampler.getMemberNames;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import org.as3commons.bytecode.swf.SWFFile;
    import org.as3commons.bytecode.swf.SWFFileIO;
    import org.as3commons.bytecode.tags.DoABCTag;

    public class AdvancedInfo extends Sprite{

        private var cursor:Point = new Point();
        private var methodInfo:Array;

        public function AdvancedInfo(){
            init();
        }
        private function init():void{
            var byteLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('B.swf'));
            byteLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            byteLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,bytesLoaded);
        }
        private function bytesLoaded(event:Event):void{
            var ba:ByteArray = event.target.data as ByteArray;//get swf bytes
            var swfFile:SWFFile = new SWFFileIO().read(ba);//read the bytes using as3-commons
            var abcTags:Array = swfFile.getTagsByType(DoABCTag);//get actionscript bytecode (ABC) tags
            for each(var tag:DoABCTag in abcTags) methodInfo = tag.abcFile.methodInfo;//loop though tags and get method information
            //display and rollOver
            var d:Loader = addChild(new Loader()) as Loader;
            d.loadBytes(ba);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rolledOver,true,0,true);
        }
        private function getMethodDetails(methodName:String):String{
            var result:String = '';
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < methodInfo.length; i++){
                if(methodInfo[i].methodName == methodName){
                    result += 'signature:\t'+methodInfo[i]+'\n';
                    result += 'body:\t'+methodInfo[i].methodBody;
                    return result;
                }
              }
            return result;
        }
        private function rolledOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
            cursor.x = mouseX;cursor.y = mouseY;
            var obj:Array = getObjectsUnderPoint(cursor);
            var numObj:int = obj.length; 
            for(var i:int = 0 ; i < numObj ; i++){
                if(obj[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER) || obj[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)){
                    var members:Object = getMemberNames(obj[i]);
                    for each (var name:QName in members){
                        if (name.localName == "listeners"){
                            for (var j : int = 0; j < obj[i][name].length; j++){
                                var func:Function = obj[i][name][j];
                                try{
                                    func.call();
                                }catch(error:Error){
                                    var methodName:String = error.message.split('on ')[1].split('.')[0].split('/')[1].split('()')[0]; 
                                    trace(getMethodDetails(methodName));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For documentation purposes here's the code for the SWF I loaded:

```
package {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class B extends Sprite {
        public function B() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
        }
        private function init(event:Event = null) : void {
            for (var i : int = 0; i < 1000 ; i++) {
                var b:Sprite = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
                b.graphics.lineStyle(Math.random()*3);
                b.graphics.drawCircle(-3, -3, 3);
                b.x = 3+Math.random() * stage.stageWidth - 6;
                b.y = 3+Math.random() * stage.stageHeight - 6;
                b.buttonMode = true;
                b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);
            }
        }
        private function onRollOver(event : MouseEvent) : void {
            event.currentTarget.scaleX = event.currentTarget.scaleY = .1 + Math.random() * 2.1;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a sample of the method detail trace using the getMethodDetails in my AdvancedInfo example:

```
signature:  private function QName[Namespace[private::B]:onRollOver](QName[Namespace[public::flash.events]:MouseEvent]) : QName[Namespace[public]:void]
body:   
    private function QName[Namespace[private::B]:onRollOver](QName[Namespace[public::flash.events]:MouseEvent]) : QName[Namespace[public]:void]
    {   
        //maxStack=5, localCount=3, initScopeDepth=9, maxScopeDepth=10
        0:debugfile     [/Users/george/Documents/Flex Builder 3/Del/src;;B.as]:2
        2:debugline     [28]:4
        4:getlocal_0        :5
        5:pushscope     :6
        6:debug     [1, 18, 0, 28]:11
        11:debugline        [29]:13
        13:getlocal_1       :14
        14:getproperty      [QName[Namespace[public]:currentTarget]]:16
        16:getlocal_1       :17
        17:getproperty      [QName[Namespace[public]:currentTarget]]:19
        19:pushdouble       [0.1]:21
        21:getlex       [QName[Namespace[public]:Math]]:23
        23:callproperty     [QName[Namespace[public]:random], 0]:26
        26:pushdouble       [2.1]:28
        28:multiply     :29
        29:add      :30
        30:dup      :31
        31:setlocal_2       :32
        32:setproperty      [Multiname[name=scaleY, nsset=[Namespace[private::B], Namespace[public], Namespace[private::B.as$25], Namespace[packageInternalNamespace], Namespace[namespace::http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin], Namespace[protectedNamespace::B], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::B], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:Sprite], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:InteractiveObject], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:DisplayObject], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.events:EventDispatcher], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::Object]]]]:34
        34:getlocal_2       :35
        35:kill     [2]:37
        37:setproperty      [Multiname[name=scaleX, nsset=[Namespace[private::B], Namespace[public], Namespace[private::B.as$25], Namespace[packageInternalNamespace], Namespace[namespace::http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin], Namespace[protectedNamespace::B], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::B], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:Sprite], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:InteractiveObject], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.display:DisplayObject], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::flash.events:EventDispatcher], Namespace[staticProtectedNamespace::Object]]]]:39
        39:debugline        [30]:41
        41:returnvoid       :42
    }
traits=(no traits)
```

For more information on the AVM2 instructions visit the [documentation](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/AVM2/5.+AVM2+instructions) or the [SWF File format specs](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) (PDF link).

Other options that involve 3rd party software which I haven't fully explored would be:

1. Using [FlashFirebug](http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug) - Personally I haven't managed to get it
   running, maybe I didn't setup correctly.
2. Use getObjectsUnderPoint to trace information on objects(instance name/etc.) with rollover/mouseover handlers and then use a commercial decompiler to look for the handler using the information gained.

HTH

Answer (score 5):

If you try the following you'll be able to trace every listener on your object. It'll call all the listeners without any arguments which will throw an error. If you catch the error you can parse `error.getStackTrace` to see the locations of the listeners.

```
var members:Object = getMemberNames(yourObject);

for each (var name:QName in members) 
{
    if (name.localName == "listeners") 
    {
        for (var i : int = 0; i < yourObject[name].length; i++) 
        {
            var func:Function = yourObject[name][i];

            try
            {
                func.call();
            }
            catch(error:Error)
            {
                trace(error.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

(just to be sure, you'll need a Debug Player for this)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible unless you override `addEventListener` and keep track of the added listeners yourself.

The only similar method provided by the native [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) is `hasEventListener` which would only allow you to check whether or not there is a registered listener for a given event type.

Comment: Even if this is not part of the standard Flash environment, maybe there's a debugger that can help?

Comment: @Radu you can see all the attached listeners in a debugger like the one that comes with Flash Builder. However these only show up as a "Function pointer", which doesn't tell you the exact function (unless you somehow resolve that memory address).

Comment: How do I see all the attached listeners in the Flash Builder debugger?

Comment: You can browse the listeners array in the debugger. But it only contains `Function` pointers. Not much of a use honestly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would help you to know the event flow in AS3: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html

In short, there are two phases, Capturing and Bubbling. You are interested in the bubbling phase, when the event travels from the bottom to the top of the display stack. In this phase, various objects catch the event as it travels and execute various event listeners (the methods you are interested in). If you have access to the source code of these objects, you can insert a debug message in these methods.

I can't think of anything else.

Comment: That's the thing, I do have access to the source code, but there are many things going on, and I don't know what are all the methods that get called. I'm looking for a way to isolate these methods and see which ones they are.

Answer (score 2):

How large is the source code?  You may be able to get away with performing a project search for "addEventListener(MouseEvent".  Put breakpoints on the function reference for every instance you can, and see which one is firing for the behaviour you're looking for.  Probably a little more work than you're hoping for, but it's an idea.

Note, there are other ways that an application could trigger mouse-over-like behaviour.  For example, MovieClip instances have a mouseX and mouseY property that someone could be monitoring on an Event.ENTER_FRAME listener to trigger a visual change as well.  You may need to inspect for that behaviour as well.

Comment: Too large for that. I weeded out all possible `ENTER_FRAME`s.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your code, use trace("this was called") in the functions you want to monitor if called
2. Install Flash debugger versions http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
3. You can monitor traces at runtime with http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/

Comment: i'm pretty sure the OP meant that he is looking for a way to view which internal events and methods get called, not his own.