# Find all breakpoints in Adobe Animate

Tags: flash, animate-cc

I'm updating an old `.fla` that was created in an old version of 'Adobe Flash Professional'.

I am now using 'Adobe Animate CC' however when I attempt to save the `.fla`, I get an alert warning saying...

> This file contains the following data that will be lost if saved in the Animate CC 2017 format: 
>  - Breakpoints 
>  Continue with save?

I don't care about the breakpoints... Is there a way to either:

a) Find all breakpoints and remove; or

b) Suppress this message

Comment: for pragmatic reasons, option b makes sense. I haven't kept up to date, but you can try some of these [ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092377/finding-actionscript-within-an-fla-file/3092837#3092837)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I had a look, but nothing suggested seemed able to simply locate breakpoints.. None of them trigger when I run the application in debug mode either - so it's just sitting in some random outdated file somewhere....

Comment: I haven't touched Animate/Flash in a few good years, so unfortunately I'm out of date. Would it be possible to save the .fla to an older format that strips actionscript ? what about the .xfl format, at least you could search for actionscript using a text editor ? The other thing that comes to mind is using decompiler on the swf (software or as [library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258740/flash-events-on-mouse-over/7303353#7303353)) - the idea is to identify ABCTags (actionscript bytecode) and remove them.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks for the suggestions, I will have a play around with those suggestions... Seems like a bit of an oversight not to be able to view something so common.... I wish I was in the same boat as you, but unfortunately I have to update this old project and relive the painful flash times.